# How to load local media file in nw.js?

Tags: javascript, nwjs

I'm writing a nw.js desktop app. And I want to play some audio file on html page.

If I load some audio from the app path, it will work, like `<audio src="test.wav"></audio>`

However , for most time. I'd like to load some other audio file on my computer,out of the app folder. Which didn't work.
the code is below:

So what is the right way to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>test audio</title>
</head>
<body style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <audio src="/Users/shidanlifuhetian/Desktop/45.wav" crossorigin="anonymous" controls="controls">

    </audio>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe deleting the first "/" of the route or changing the route to "./"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after several try.

just add `file://` before src attribute.

like this:

```
   <audio src="file:///Users/shidanlifuhetian/Desktop/45.wav" crossorigin="anonymous" controls="controls">
    </audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the exact folder structure and got the following error in console: *Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND*

I was able to fix it by providing the absolute path to the file like this

```
<audio src="C:/Users/shidanlifuhetian/Desktop/45.wav" crossorigin="anonymous" controls="controls">
</audio>
```

or like this

```
<audio src="C:\\Users\\shidanlifuhetian\\Desktop\\45.wav" crossorigin="anonymous" controls="controls">
</audio>
```